# how to create a .sql file from terminal in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu

I have created a project which is using a database , prepared in mysql. To submit this project i need to create a .sql file. 
I am not using workbench. Can any one guide me on how to make the .sql file using terminal. I have created all of my database using terminal. I am working on ubuntu.

Comment: You want to create a dump file from terminal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nysqldump -u db_username -p database_name > database_name.sql
```

Then enter and it will ask the password, enter the password and and hit enter, thats it it will create the .sql file for you

Here is an example in my ubuntu machine

```
abhik@ubuntu-desktop:~$ mysqldump -u root -p test >test.sql
Enter password: 
abhik@ubuntu-desktop:~$
```

I am currently on Desktop folder so the file is saved under Desktop

Comment: thankyou. But when i press enter it just gives me an arrow in the prompt...something like this ->

Comment: Make sure you are not logged in to the mysql while doing dump, it needs to be without login see my update.

Answer (score 0):

If you want To export:

```
 mysqldump -u mysql_user -p DATABASE_NAME > backup.sql
```

To import:

```
 mysql -u mysql_user -p DATABASE < backup.sql
```

Comment: your welcome .. Please vote up if this answer is usefull  CHeers! :-)